# How to Set DropdownList 1st element text in center and Keep Rest left aligned?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, text-alignment

I have an asp dropdownlist, I have "Select Option" as the first element in dropdown. All elements in dropdown including 1st are aligned left automatically. If I set text-align to center, all the list items are getting aligned to center, which I dont want. I only need to set the 1st element (Header) of dropdown in center. How to do it ?

Comment: If my reply has helped you, please mark it as correct. If there are any issues with my code let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a CSS class to the first item in the drop down list on page load:

```
test.Items[0].Attributes["class"] = "header";
```

Then you can apply specific styles to the "header" class in your CSS file.